# why 2^29-1 is the biggest key in protocol buffers

Tags: protocols, protocol-buffers

2^29 -1 ? 
Because "Field numbers 1-15 have a 1-byte tag."
32-byte don't have the tag? I know the 3-byte,but why don`t have the tag?

Is that varint? I can`t understanding the protobuf\descriptor.cc source code.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All fields have a tag, but for field numbers 16 and higher the tag takes multiple bytes. So field numbers 1 to 15 should be used for the most common fields. And yes, the encoding is varint.

The largest key is 2^29 because the lowest 3 bits are used to store the field datatype. So 29 + 3 = 32 fits neatly into `uint32_t`.

You will find more information here:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#structure

Comment: the largest key 2^29 where the tag?

Comment: 7 bits per byte,one bit is tag,so 4*7 = 28 ,28 - lowest 3 = 25 is not 29

Comment: @diwangkai Unfortunately I do not understand what you are trying to say. There is no reason to limit the 7-bit varint encoding to 4 bytes. And I have no idea what "one bit is tag" means.

Comment: numbers 1 -15 only one byte because   8 bits -1 bit tag  - lowest 3 bits = 4 bits,2^4 = 16 ok,that's 1-15;
numbers 2^29-1 four bytes ,32 bits - 4 bits tag - lowest 3 bits = 25 bits,is not    29 bits ,not 2^29-1 ,is 2^25-1 for largest.

Comment: There is no need to limit varints to 4 bytes. The uint32_t limit is for convenience for the in-memory representation, before encoding or after decoding. And also, in protobuf "tag" generally means the tag number specified in .proto. The usual term for the top bit in varints is "continuation bit" or just "msb".

Comment: I want to see the source code ...I want to know how to work.Can you show me where in source code?

Comment: I`m waiting for you~~